# Automation Error on a Link

Tags: vba, excel

I am using a macro to login to a website and select several values from drop-down menus, which works up until the point where I try to submit it, where I get a `Automation Error` on the following line:

`.document.getElementById("butRunReport")(0).Click`

The link it's referring to on the page looks like this:

`<a onclick="return validateRep();" id="butRunReport" title="Run Report" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" alternatetext="Run Report" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainBodyContent$butRunReport','')"><i class="fa fa-search fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> View</a>`

I have tried variations of the line, without any success.

What would I need to do to fix this?

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT:**

I was eventually able to come across a solution to my problem.

The line `.document.getElementById("butRunReport")(0).Click` needed to be replaced with:

`For Each l In objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
    If l.innerText = " View" Then
        l.Click
        Exit For
    End If
    Next`

And

`Dim l As HTMLElementCollection`

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

After doing some more digging, I found out that this would be a better approach, which also works for me:

`For Each l In objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
    If l.innerText = " View" Then
        l.Click
        Exit For
    End If
   Next`

With: `Dim l As HTMLElementCollection`

Thanks!